# Ruby - Why is a variable a valid statement?

Tags: ruby

I'm fairly new to Ruby (coming from C#), so I'm wondering why this is valid:

```
x = 2
x #why is this valid?
```

Does ruby interpret it as x.inspect or something internally?

Comment: The most common use of a naked variable is probably as the last line of a method, in order that the method return the value of that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Ruby follows the Lisp where [expressions return their own value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29#Evaluation_and_the_read.E2.80.93eval.E2.80.93print_loop), and, in particular, [some expressions are self-evaluating](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Self_002dEvaluating-Forms.html). As a result, `return` is actually [unnecessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601498/what-is-the-point-of-return-in-ruby) in Ruby.

Comment: More or less what I was looking for. The concept seemed foreign, but I guess this behavior also applies to other languages. Good links, btw.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is a variable a valid statement?

Because it isn't a statement, it's an expression. There are no statements in Ruby, everything is an expression.

> Does ruby interpret it as `x.inspect` or something internally?

No. `x` is interpreted as `x`, nothing else.

In a REPL, like IRb or Pry, the REPL may or may not call some methods on the object which is the result of evaluating `x` in order to display some human-readable text representation of the object, but that is a) a feature of the REPL, not Ruby and b) applies to all expressions, not just local variable dereferences.

Answer (score 0):

It is valid because `x` is a defined variable, i.e., it refers to an object. It doesn't interpret it as `x.inspect` or anything else. `x` is `x` (actually `2`).