# Change the value of a described_class.new argument

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I have the following code:

```
require 'command'

describe Command do
  subject(:command) { described_class.new(input, robotic_rover) }

  let(:robotic_rover) do
    double(:robotic_rover, position: '0 0 N',
                           move: '0 1 N',
                           right_turn: '0 0 E',
                           left_turn: '0 0 W')
  end

  describe 'advance command' do
    let(:input) { 'M' }

    describe 'initialization' do
      it 'alters a rovers position' do
        expect(command.position_change).to eq robotic_rover.move
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'right command' do
    let(:input) { 'R' }

    describe 'initialization' do
      it 'alters a rovers direction' do
        expect(command.position_change).to eq robotic_rover.right_turn
      end
    end
  end

  describe 'left command' do
      let(:input) { 'L' }

    describe 'initialization' do
      it 'alters the rovers direction' do
        expect(command.position_change).to eq robotic_rover.left_turn
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Inside each of the initial describe blocks (advance command, right command and left command), I have attempted to define the value for the `input` argument passed into the `described_class.new(input, robotic_rover)` with a `let`.

What happens is that only the last test (left command), passes and the first two tests (advance command, and right command) fail with:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(command.position_change).to eq robotic_rover.right_turn

   expected: "0 0 E"
        got: nil
```

If I remove the let from each of the first two tests, then they fail with:

```
 Failure/Error: subject(:command) { described_class.new(input, robotic_rover) }

 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `input' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Command::AdvanceCommand::Initialization:0x007f90cc14f758>
```

can anyone help me with changing the value of that `initialize` argument for each of the describe blocks?

**The Code**

Intention with this code is to refactor it out of the multiple if's but for now, it's all I've got.

```
class Command
  attr_reader :input, :robotic_rover

  def initialize(input, robotic_rover)
    @input         = input
    @robotic_rover = robotic_rover
  end

  def position_change
    robotic_rover.move if input == 'M'
    robotic_rover.right_turn if input == 'R'
    robotic_rover.left_turn if input == 'L'
  end
end
```

Comment: Does not look like the issue is with the Spec. Could we have a look at the code that is controller the switch based on the input?

Spec refactor if it helps https://gist.github.com/ChuckJHardy/ea62ef16df72901aa65230b06cdfd9f6

Comment: @CharlesJHardy Take a look at the latest edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are missing the `return` for each conditional in the `#position_change` method.

[what is the point of return in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601498/what-is-the-point-of-return-in-ruby)

```
class Command
  attr_reader :input, :robotic_rover

  def initialize(input, robotic_rover)
    @input         = input
    @robotic_rover = robotic_rover
  end

  def position_change
    return robotic_rover.move if input == 'M'
    return robotic_rover.right_turn if input == 'R'
    return robotic_rover.left_turn if input == 'L'
  end
end

describe Command do
  let(:instance) { described_class.new(input, robotic_rover) }

  let(:robotic_rover) do
    double(
      "RoboticRover",
      position: '0 0 N',
      move: '0 1 N',
      right_turn: '0 0 E',
      left_turn: '0 0 W'
    )
  end

  describe '#position_change' do
    subject(:position_change) { instance.position_change }

    context 'when advance command' do
      let(:input) { 'M' }

      it 'alters a rovers position' do
        expect(position_change).to eq robotic_rover.move
      end
    end

    context 'when right command' do
      let(:input) { 'R' }

      it 'alters a rovers direction' do
        expect(position_change).to eq robotic_rover.right_turn
      end
    end

    context 'when left command' do
      let(:input) { 'L' }

      it 'alters the rovers direction' do
        expect(position_change).to eq robotic_rover.left_turn
      end
    end
  end
end
```