# Ruby - Last value of a isn't printed

Tags: ruby

I write a ruby program that prints 3 different values of variable a with different data types:

```
a = 5
puts a
a = true
puts a
a = 1.325
return a
puts a
```

In this case, last value didn't print. When i remove return a, program prints a last value, 1.325.
**But how?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601498/what-is-the-point-of-return-in-ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` controls program flow, calling it will exit the current method and pass the value of `a` into whatever expression called it.

Usually you would not write a method with an unconditional `return` and more code afterward, because that code is not reachable. The `puts` in your example will never be called. Just move it to before the `return` expression if you want it to run.